# KeyError: '"param1"' when creating a dictionary string

Tags: python, string

I need to create a dictionary string:

```
param1 = "abc"
param2 = "def"
input_data = """{"param1": {}, "param2": {}}""".format(param1, param2)
```

But I get this error:

```
KeyError: '"param1"'
```

Comment: You need to double those outer pair of curly braces, so that `.format()` treats them as literals, rather than a third thing to be replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format string is seeing the first `{` as the start of a formatter, so you have to escape it by using a double `{{`:

```
 input_data = """{{"param1": {}, "param2": {}}}""".format(param1, param2)
```

Comment: Thanks, what if I want to load it using: json.loads(input_data)? It does not seem to work.

Comment: If you eventually want to pass it to something that loads json, you should use json.dumps() to create the string rather than trying to do it manually.  `input_data = json.dumps({"param1": {}, "param2": {})`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape (double) characters `{` and `}` in format strings when they represent themselves (not used for formatting):

```
param1 = "abc"
param2 = "def"
input_data = """{{"param1": {}, "param2": {}}}""".format(param1, param2)
```

Comment: Whe could add that here `input_data` will be of type `str` (for comparison with @top talent answer).

Comment: @Rivers as I understood from the title and the question, that's the OP's intention.

Comment: Absolutely, I agree, that was not a negative criticism. I added this comment only for comparison purposes with the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this way.

```
param1 = "abc", param2 = "def"
input_data = str({"param1": param1, "param2": param2})
```

Output of `input_data`:

```
"{'param1': 'abc', 'param2': 'def'}"
```

Comment: Whe could add that here `input_data` will be of type `dict` (for comparison with @bereal answer).

Comment: Thanks, what if I want to load it using: json.loads(input_data)? It does not seem to work.

Comment: @Fluxy if you want to load it using `json.loads`, why don't you serialize using `json.dumps`?

Comment: @bereal: I posted this question separately. Here is the link in case you'd like to answer it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67606663/backend-returns-response-502-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers