# Backend returns <Response [502]> (TypeError: string indices must be integers)

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I want to send the REST request to the end-point.

```
import requests

param1 = "abc"
param2 = "def"

input_data = """{{"param1": {}, "param2": {}}}""".format(param1, param2)

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
resp = requests.post(scoring_uri, input_data, headers=headers)
resp
```

However, I get the error response:

```
<Response [502]>
```

Logs:

```
param1 = request[\'param1\']\nTypeError: string indices must be integers
```

How can I fix it (either on the backend side or on the request sending side).

Comment: Apparently, `request` is a string, not a dictionary

Comment: @ForceBru: Hmm, so how could I pass it as a dictionary to the end-point?

Comment: Basically, `input_data` can be a regular dictionary - `requests` will handle everything for you.

Comment: @Fluxy, haha, you made a mistake in request parameters

Comment: @toptalent: which one?

Comment: in the middle, there is request part how to post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send `json` data to server, you can use `json=` parameter:

```py
import requests

param1 = "abc"
param2 = "def"

payload = {"param1": param1, "param2": param2}

resp = requests.post(scoring_uri, json=payload, headers=headers)
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and still got `param1 = request[\'param1\']\nTypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: @Fluxy The `payload` variable should be normal python dictionary. `requests` will send Json request to the server.

Comment: No, sorry, getting this: `parameters = json.loads(request)\n  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_xxxxx/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads\n    return _default_decoder.decode(s)\n`

Comment: @Fluxy Use `resp = requests.post(scoring_uri, json=payload, headers=headers).json()` do decode the Json response (note the `.json()` at the end)

Comment: I applied your code. But I think that the issue is on the backend side. I added `print` of request in the backend and this is what it prints:
`request received: {"param2": "abc", "param2": "def"}`. And then it says `param1 = request[\'param1\']\nTypeError: string indices must be integers`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, and get reference from [here](https://pynative.com/python-post-json-using-requests-library/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20have%20data%20in,it%20into%20JSON%20like%20this.&text=Use%20The%20json%20parameter%3A%20The,json%20parameter%20of%20the%20requests.)

```
input_data = {"param1": param1, "param2": param2}
resp = requests.post(scoring_uri, json=input_data, headers=headers)
```

Then

```
param1 = request["param1"]
```

Comment: What's the difference, though? This is the same as OP's code

Comment: On the backend side, it does not work because `request` arrives as a string to the backend. I've just found it out by doing `print(type(request))` in the backend. Therefore I'm still getting the same error. Should I do `json.dumps(request)` in the backend?